# Write millions of documents into Riak

Tags: bigdata, bulkinsert, riak

What is the best way to add huge amount of documents into riak? Let's say there are millions of product records, which change very often (prices, ...) and we want to update all of them very frequently. Is there a better way than replace keys one by one in Riak? Something as bulk set of 1000 documents at once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unfortunately not any bulk operations available in Riak, so this has to be done by updating each object individually. If your updates however arrive in bulks, it may be worthwhile revisiting your data model. If you can de-normalise your products, perhaps by storing a range of products in a single object, it might be possible to reduce the number of updates that need to be performed by grouping them, thereby reducing the load on the cluster.

When modelling data in Riak you usually need to look at access and query patterns in addition to the structure of the data, and make sure that the model supports all types of queries and latency requirements. This quite often means de-normalising your model by either grouping or duplicating data in order to ensure that updates and queries can be performed as efficiently as possible, ideally through direct K/V access.